# Condição ternária no Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Gostaria de poder fazer isso:

```
{% if is_premium > 0 %}
    <span class="text-success d-block">Você é Premium e possui {{ is_premium }} {{ ' dias' if is_premium > 1 else ' dia' }}</span>
{% else %}
    <span class="text-danger d-block">Você não é Premium</span>
{% endif %}
```

Com isto:

```
{% if is_premium > 0 %}
    {% if is_premium > 1 %}
        <span class="text-success d-block">Você é Premium e possui {{ is_premium }} dias</span>
    {% else %}
        <span class="text-success d-block">Você é Premium e possui {{ is_premium }} dia</span>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    <span class="text-danger d-block">Você não é Premium</span>
{% endif %}
```

Só que o Django não aceita este tipo de condição:

```
{{ ' dias' if is_premium > 1 else ' dia' }}
```

O Django possui alguma funcionalidade parecida no sistema de templates?

Vou ser sincero, foquei tanto em `models` que acabei lendo pouco a documentação que fala sobre os templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viva podes ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110166/django-template-ternary-operator), ou seja, existem várias formas de utilizar o condição ternary:

```
{% firstof var1 var2 var3 %}
```

Ou

```
{{ value|yesno:"yeah,no,maybe" }}
```

No link acima tens mais exemplos.